# waiting token value from RegistrationIntentService

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm an android developer and I'm facing an issue while working on a **library project**.
I want wait until the token value returned by the RegistrationIntentService.

Please see  my first approach with a thread :

I want my main thread to wait for another thread ( which contains the registration Intent service ) before continuing and then return a value set by my other thread.

```
public  Data a(Activity activity){
    Data data = new Data(); 
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity,RegistrationIntentService.class);
            activity.startService(intent);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    // I want my main thread finish until the onHandleIntent of RegistrationIntentService finish 
    //continue to return data
    return data;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can do `thread.join` to wait for termination, but in this example it is not clear why do you need additional thread at all

Comment: @hoaz i already test with join() and that's not resolved my issue . I think the thread is not the good approach to wait the token returned by RegistrationIntentService

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for a thread to complete before you return something, You can use a executor service to start the thread and await for termination of the thread. Please find a sample code as follows,

```
public String myMethod() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do Thread Stuff here
            }
        };

        java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService exec = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        exec.execute(t);

        // terminate executor after current thread
        exec.shutdown();

        try {
            // Wait till thread completes
            exec.awaitTermination(1, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Handle Exception
        }

        return "Success";
    }
```

Comment: Ok  thanks it's look fine but i suppose with your example, after test it , the thread is not the solution about my issue. I think the real question it should be  : **how wait the token value returned by onHandleIntent() from RegistrationIntentService ?**

Comment: @el_fr_chiquito Be specific about your question. I thought you want to return something after a thread completes.